# How to use only a part of rxjs-compat, or write a custom rxjs-compat?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-compat

We've [updated](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) our project to use Angular & Rxjs 6 and all works fine.

We've also updated the code to use the pipe operators, so we would like to drop `rxjs-compat`.
The only issue is that one of our dependencies still uses the old import syntax for Observable and Subject.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

Is there any way to provide our own minimal rxjs-compat just for these two classes?

The library does not do anything fancy with Observable and Subject, and doesn't use any operators, so it seems overkill to import the full rxjs-compat package.

Comment: You might be able to do something using the `paths` setting in the `tsconfig.json` file's `compilerOptions` - that is, redirect `rxjs-compat` to someplace else - but I've never tried this with a dependency's dependencies. But does it really matter? Won't tree shaking effect the same result?

Comment: @cartant tree-shaking doesn't seem to work with rxjs-compat. I've tried the `paths` trick you mentioned, but it didn't seem to have the effect I was expecting ... I'm probably doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to copy any files when using the `paths` option.

I'd try something like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "rxjs/Observable": ["./node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable"],
        "rxjs/Subject": ["./node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subject"]
    }
}
```

Note that `baseUrl` must be specified.

The question is whether or not the `paths` option affects other dependencies in `node_modules`. I'm not sure and I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `paths` as metioned by @cartant I managed to get it to compile without `rxjs-compat`, but the output `main.js` is even larger than using the full compat library...

- With `rxjs-compat` = 691 KB
- With patched library import = 671 KB (ideal size)
- with `rxjs-compat` paths hack = 700 KB

I've probably done something wrong, but I don't have time to investigate this further.

Steps for the hack:

1. Create a folder `src\rxjs-compat\node_modules` (note the node_modules name, it's used to bypass a [webpack bug](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3160))
2. Copy the `d.ts` and `.js` files you need from `rxjs-compat` (in my case Observable and Subject)
3. Edit tsconfig.app.json and add the following paths in the compilerOptions:

   `"paths": {
     "rxjs-compat/Observable": [ "rxjs-compat/node_modules/Observable"],
     "rxjs/Subject": [ "rxjs-compat/node_modules/Subject"]
   }`